# need help to construct query

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following two tables and would like to construct a select query that will match the fields between the tables:

```
 tablename       columnname           size  order
    employee        name               25    1
    employee        sex                25    2
    employee        contactNumber      50    3
    employee        salary             25    4
    address         street             25    5
    address         country            25    6
```

from this i would like to construct query like

```
select 
        T1.name,
        T1.sex,
        T1.contactNumber,
        T1.salary,
        T2.street,
        T2.contry 
from tablename1[employee] T1,
     tablename2[address] T2
```

how to construct the above query, here table name can be `N` also the `columname` can be also `N`.

Comment: `salary` should be under `employee` and not `address`. follow [tutorial for jdbc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html)

Comment: show some Java code have u atleast been successful at connecting to your DB??

Comment: @Learner what are you using in JAVA to store above mentioned values like tablename,columnname etc.

Comment: @jaychapani thanks for the comment, i am really new guy to java, i don't even know where to store the above value and how to retrive them to construct query. if you can extend your help it would be better and thanks for the effort

Comment: @Learner can you pls code that gives you above result.

Comment: @jaychapani thanks i shall code the above result and get back, meanwhile please try your best if possible

Comment: @jaychapani can you please give me a clue how to store the above values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a foreighn key column in table 2 so that you can join it to table 1 on id.Also the query you are using will fetch a cartisian product.

```
select 
    T1.name,
    T1.sex,
    T1.contactNumber,
    T1.salary,
    T2.street,
    T2.contry 
from tablename1[employee] T1
left join tablename2[address] T2 on T2.employee_id = T1.id
```

Comment: By preforming left join you're selecting ALL the records from `T1` and only the matching records from `T2` which is good if there's one-to-one matching between the tables and less good if some information is missing (in `T2`) and you want to select only the employees with FULL data, then you'll need to use an `inner join` like I wrote in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

@Learner: in the current situation there is no way to cross-reference between the tables (Google: `foreign-key`). 
What you want to do is to add a new-column to both tables which will be called `employee_id`, then you'll be able to get the data by:

```
select T1.*, T2.*
from employee T1, address T2
where T1.employee_id = T2.employee_id
```

Comment: the table name and column name are stored in few tables from that i am able to get he desired table and column names but from that i have to construct the query to get values, the query i have given is just example of how the query should be

Comment: @Learner as you can see, 3 different people couldn't understand your question. Please provide a *real* example with *real* data. Your question is too vague and can't be answered in the current format.

Comment: thanks for the effort, if you see my question there is table which contains tablename,columnname,size,order i have a query which retunrs this, from the returned results i have to contruct a query in using java which will look like above answer and that will bring the values.

Comment: I still don't understand your question: you say you need to construct such a query in Java,  well, why don't you do it ? what's the issue ? where is your Java-code, does it fail ? if so, on which line ? what's the error ? A tip for better life as a programmer: when you ask a question, try to imagine you're someone else, then read your question and see if it's clear ;)